# Match any lowercase/uppercase chained character and add an additional one

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

In Javascript, I would like to do the following.
When I match a lowerCase followed by a upperCase, I would like to add a special character in beetween it.

ex :

- myHouse => my_House
- aRandomString => a_Random_String

etc...

I made a regex for this match =>

`/([a-z][A-Z](.{0}))+/g`

the problem I have is if I do

`"aRandomString".replace(/([a-z][A-Z](.{0}))+/g, '_')`

it will of course do => _ando_tring

EDIT :

I made this but, isn't this overly complicated ?

```js
var mString = "aRandomString";
var match = mString.match(/([a-z][A-Z](.{0}))+/g, '_')
var save = [...match]
match = match.map(e => [e.slice(0, 1), '_', e.slice(1)].join(''))
save.forEach((s,i) => mString = mString.replace(s, match[i]))
console.log(mString)
```

Comment: `str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => \`_${letter}\``

Comment: @Bobby ... what should happen with a string value like `aTestStringForMULTIPLEUpperCase` as Henry was choosing it for the example code? Does one expect `..._MULTIPLEUpper_Case`, which will be the result for any solution which exactly matches your task, or does one rather expect `..._MULTIPLE_Upper_Case` which was more logic?

Comment: hiw version is ok, what I need is just a `_` when there is lower followed by upper. no matter if it cut words or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can easily match just the lowercase, uppercase pattern you are looking for and replace with a [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```js
const mString = "aTestStringForMULTIPLEUpperCase";
const uString = mString.replace(/[a-z][A-Z]/g, v => `${v[0]}_${v[1]}`);
console.log(uString);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [more robust/generic approach](https://regex101.com/r/OpmSbx/1), which takes an additional uppercase boundary into account (not only lower followed by upper but also an upper in between another left side upper and right side lower) might look like that ...

```js
const regXUppecaseBoundaries = (/(?:(?<=[a-z])[A-Z])|(?:(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z](?=[a-z]))/g);

const sampleText = `myHouse aRandomString
aRandomString aTestStringForMULTIPLEUpperCase
myHouse AaAAaTestStringForMULTIPLEUpperCase`;

// also check ... [https://regex101.com/r/OpmSbx/1]
console.log(
  sampleText.replace(regXUppecaseBoundaries, '_$&')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```